# Uploading files to a folder that is above the current folder

Tags: php

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM media WHERE path = '$target'");
if($row = mysql_num_rows($result)==1)
{
echo"<br />Sorry, there is already a file with that name on the server.<br     />Please press back on your browser and save the file under a different name.";
}else{

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target))
{
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']). " has been uploaded";
mysql_query("INSERT INTO media (id, related_page_id, type, title, copy, path, position, assets, time) VALUES ('', '$cat','$type','$name','','$target','$position','$id','$today')");

header("Location: edit.php?category=$cat");
exit();
echo $name;
}
else {
echo $today;
echo "<br />";
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file. Please press back on your browser and try again.";
}
}
```

The above code used to work. Now it will not let me upload files to ../uploads/ but it works fine if i upload to uploads/.
Does anyone have any suggestions as to what i'm doing wrong? Thanks

EDIT

```
$target = "../uploads/";
```

Comment: Can you paste where you set '$target'? And what does it say when you try to upload to './uploads/'?

Comment: I get a "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file. Please press back on your browser and try again" error

Comment: Another thing to note is that you shouldn't output any text prior to running your header() function. And your echo "The file...has been uploaded" statement should probably follow the query after it, and be displayed conditionally, depending on the outcome of your INSERT.

Comment: You should have an OR DIE(mysql_error()) in there as well, to capture any error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it sounds silly but are the permissions for the folder set up correctly?

Comment: That's the thing. It used to work. It has only just become a problem

Comment: Damn folder permissions. One of my seniors changed them without telling me!

Comment: Glad to have helped. Enjoy :)